# RabbitMQ be sure message reaches a queue

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I want to be sure the message is reaching a queue.
Otherwise, I want an exception.

I have tried publisher returns, but it is not what I need, because it is on a different thread and I think it would be tricky to somehow wait for it on the thread sent the message.

Without the transacted channel, the convertAndSend method returned successfully when the exchange did not be there, with the transacted channel now it throws an exception.

What I need is the same when there is no route based on the routing key.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getGlobal();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setReturnCallback((message, replyCode, replyText, exchange, routingKey) -> log.info(replyCode + "," + replyText));
        rabbitTemplate.setChannelTransacted(true);
        rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        return args -> {
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("exchangeName", "routingKey", "message");
            log.info("Send is done.");
        };
    }
}
```

only property: spring.rabbitmq.publisher-returns=true

Spring boot version: 2.1.7.RELEASE

**Actual**:

> no exchange -> convertAndSend throws exception
>
> no route at exchange -> method returns

**Expected**:

> no exchange -> convertAndSend throws exception
>
> no route at exchange -> convertAndSend throws exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use publisher confirms and correlation data:

```
spring.rabbitmq.publisher-returns=true
spring.rabbitmq.publisher-confirms=true
spring.rabbitmq.template.mandatory=true
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So57464212Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So57464212Application.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        template.setReturnCallback((message, replyCode, replyText, exchange, routingKey) -> {
            System.err.println("Returned: " + replyText);
        });
        template.setConfirmCallback((correlationData, ack, cause) -> {
            System.err.println("ack:" + ack);
        });
        return args -> {
            CorrelationData correlationData = new CorrelationData("foo");
            template.convertAndSend("", "NOQUEUE", "bar", correlationData);
            correlationData.getFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (correlationData.getReturnedMessage() != null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Message was returned");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Now it is good when no route, but now the channel is not transacted and when there is no exchange then convertAndSend returns without an exception.

Comment: That is correct; unfortunately you can't enable transactions and confirms on a channel at the same time. I don't believe your two requirements can be satisfied, but you might try asking on the `rabbitmq-users` Google group, where the RabbitMQ engineers hang out.

Comment: We are now useing the default exchange, so the routing key is the name of the queue, works fine, thank you!